# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gradle, fasterxml, jackson-modules

I have a simple Spark program in scala with following code but get the exception.All im trying to do is run the main code.
I have also included the gradle config.
Any help will be appreciated.

Error:-

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/DefaultScalaModule$
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:714)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.parallelize(SparkContext.scala:728)...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Main:-

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("TempratureRDD")
      .setMaster("local[2]")
      .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    print("___________________________________________________________________________________________")

    val vertexArray = Array(
      (1L, ("Sensor1", 28)),
      (2L, ("Sensor2", 27)),
      (3L, ("Sensor3", 65)),
      (4L, ("Sensor4", 42)),
      (5L, ("Sensor5", 55)),
      (6L, ("Sensor6", 50))
    )
    val edgeArray = Array(
      Edge(2L, 1L, 7),
      Edge(2L, 4L, 2),
      Edge(3L, 2L, 4),
      Edge(3L, 6L, 3),
      Edge(4L, 1L, 1),
      Edge(5L, 2L, 2),
      Edge(5L, 3L, 8),
      Edge(5L, 6L, 3)
    )




    val vertexRDD: RDD[(Long, (String, Int))] = sc.parallelize(vertexArray)
    val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[Int]] = sc.parallelize(edgeArray)

    val graph: Graph[(String, Int), Int] = Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)

    for ((id,(name,age)) <- graph.vertices.filter { case (id,(name,age)) => age > 30 }.collect) {
      println(s"$name is $age")
    }

  }
```

build.gradle:-

```
dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
// The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.8'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.11
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-streaming_2.11', version: '1.6.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-mqtt_2.10
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-streaming-mqtt_2.10', version: '1.6.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3
compile group: 'org.eclipse.paho', name: 'org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3', version: '1.1.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-graphx_2.10
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-graphx_2.10', version: '2.0.0'
```

}

no other dependencies

Comment: First of all you are mixing scala versions in your dependencies... you are compiling with `2.11.8` then you have `spark-graphx_2.10` and `spark-streaming-mqtt_2.10` which were compiled against scala `2.10.x`. First fix that... and worry about everything else later on.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this issue by compiling spark with scala 2.11.8 and then including the jars thanks @Sarvesh Kumar Singh for pointing out!
See below links for HowTo's

See [Building Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html) and 
[Building Apache Spark on your Local Machine](http://www.sparktutorials.net/building-apache-spark-on-your-local-machine)

Comment: Your second link appears to be broken