# How to resolve "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" when running Scala Spark project using databricks-connect?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, exception, databricks, databricks-connect

Currently I am learning how to use databricks-connect to develop Scala code using IDE locally. The set-up of the databricks-connect as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-connect) was succuesful. This is an assumption as I can run PySpark Code against the cluster with no issues.

However, I struggle to run the scala example as provided in the Scala [demo object](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#language-scala). I receive the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`: Here the full trace of the Exception:

[image: StackTrace]

My build.sbt follows closely what was provided with the Databricks-connect demo:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.15"
name := "hello-world"
organization := "ch.epfl.scala"
version := "1.0"
//autoScalaLibrary := true
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "2.1.1"
unmanagedBase := new java.io.File("/home/clh78p/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/jars")
mainClass := Some("Main")
```

My clusters configuration is up-date and I payed close attention to following the databricks-[connect client installation manual](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#set-up-the-client) precisely.

[image: SparkConfig]

I read amongst others the [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567269/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-spark-scala) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930929/scala-spark-java-lang-classnotfoundexception). They make me think I am missing some jar or a library dependency which may not be covered in the demo? I made sure the scala versions match, so this should hopefully not be the problem. Any advice is welcome.

Note that I use VS Code with WSL2 and the Databricks Azure option. I am learning Scala at the moment to replace PySpark Notebooks.